# add filter "in stock" or "out of stock" to admin products grid

Tags: magento2

im using magento 2.4.2. Is any solution to add extra option  to filter  products in admin grid, in stock or out of stock?

Answer (score 0):

Magento default does not provide the required functionallity. You will need customisation on code level.

Refer the link - [Adding custom columns and filters](https://magecomp.com/blog/custom-filter-to-product-grid-magento-2/)